# Apache : Poodle attack complain & RC4 cipher complain even after changing ssl.conf

Tags: linux, security, debian, apache-http-server, ssl

I checked our domain on [SSL_Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com) and found out that our server is vulnerable to Poodle attack. We have a Debian System, running Apache2 as a load-balancer and failover for two Tomcat instances. I did the following changes to ssl.conf and server.xml in Apache and Tomcat respectively, restarted all of them, still SSL_Labs complains that the server is vulnerable to Poodle attack and `This server accepts RC4 cipher, but only with older protocol versions.`. What am I doing wrong.

Apache changes :

added this in ssl.conf :

```
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

Tomcat changes : added this in server.xml for https connector :

```
sslProtocol="TLS"  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
```

Is there something I am missing? Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not explicitly disabling the RC4 suite, and therefore are implicitly allowing it. You can add :!RC4 to the end, but your allowed cipher suites are not best practice, so I suggest using the line below instead:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

This is as per the recommendations from mozilla at the following link at the time of this post: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Intermediate_compatibility_.28default.29 If you are reading this after 2016, you may want to follow the link's recommendation rather than this post's.

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing part and also there was a default SSLCipherSuite line which I had to remove to make it work. Thank you. :-)